# Сравнение данных двух массивов

Tags: php, javascript, html

Привет.
У меня есть массив слов в файле, пользователь указывает необходимое кол-во и ему выводятся в рандомном порядке указанное кол-во слов из файла:

```
<?php
    $src = file("file.txt");
    $n = htmlspecialchars($_GET["words"]);
    $words = array_rand($src, $n);
    $result = array_map(function($key) use ($src) {
      return $src[$key];
    }, $words);
    echo "<div class='word'>" . implode("<hr></div><div class='word'>", $result) . "</div>"
?>
```

Выводятся в виде:

```
<div class="results center">
     <div class="word">витраж<hr></div>
     <div class="word">лапоть<hr></div>
     <div class="word">водопад<hr></div>
     <div class="word">пробка<hr></div>       
</div>
```

Возникла необходимость сделать проверку слов, которые запомнил пользователь. При нажатии на кнопку вместо слов добавляются input'ы, куда пользователь вводит значения (это я вроде бы понимаю как сделать). 
Вопрос в том, как потом сравнить массив, который выводился пользователю, со значениями который он ввел еще и в идеале вывести ему результат с ошибками.

Comment: Для вычисления схождения массивов есть array_intersect для вычисления расхождения array_diff Ваша основная задача передать на сторону сервера оба массива.

Comment: А каким образом пользователь 'запомнит' коллекцию слов?

Comment: @ddeadlink это предполагается упражнение для тренеровки памяти :) и вот я пытаюсь понять как можно реализовать возможность проверки

Comment: Вам нужно сравнить исходящие данные с данными, которые пользователь после появления инпутов введет?

Comment: @ddeadlink Да, при этом исходные данные выводятся каждый раз из  файла рандомно. Не хватает опыта придумать как это правильно сделать

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать сохранить исходные данные при загрузке страницы в [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) или [session](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) (если нужно сохранить данные на других страницах/после релоадов) , на Ваш выбор, либо в виде массива/обьекта в переменную в случае исключение выше упомянутых механизмов.

```
 var initial = document.querySelectorAll('.word'), 
               toCompare = [];
 initial.forEach(function(node) {
   toCompare.push(node.innerHTML.split('<')[0]);
 });
```

Далее можно сделать обработчик событий на изменении в новосозданных инпутах и по индексу этого самого инпута сравнивать уже с тем что Вы ранее получили